# List is changed when I update another list with same data type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My code looks like this.

```
public class Category
{
    public string CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
    public string SpecId { get; set; }
    public string SpecName { get; set; }
}

List<Category> LstCategory = new List<Category>();
List<Category> LstCatWithSpec = new List<Category>();
```

Now, I want to add category first in `LstCatWithSpec`. I copy this list in `LstCategory` and then add specialties in `LstCatWithSpec`. Now, when I update list with specialties, the list in which I copied only categories is also changed. It is also filled with specialties. It should not change right ?

How is this possible when I have two different objects and I give specific object name when I am adding items to it ?

As I am working on `xamarin.forms`, I have tagged `xamarin.forms` because I don't know if it exists in `c#` or not.

EDIT -

I tried to add list using `foreach` loop.

```
foreach( var item in LstCatWithSpec)
{
    LstCategory.Add(item); 
}
```

And I tried this also.

```
LstCategory = new List<Category>(LstCatWithSpec);
```

Comment: Please post how you copy LstCatWithSpec to LstCategory.

Comment: in both cases, you have two lists, but they both contain references to the same ITEM, and changes to that item will be reflected in both lists.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for comment. But, I have created two seperate objects with new keyword.    Then how second list is going to affect when first list is updated ? Do I have to maintain new class now ??

Comment: the only place I see you using "new" is when creating the lists.  The items in the list themselves appear to be references to the same instance.

Comment: Oh.. Ok..Got it. Thank you @Jason :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and worked

```
List<DB> List1= new List<DB>();
List<DB> List2= new List<DB>();
var DBData = List1.FirstOrDefault();
List2.Add(new DB()
            {
                field1= DBData.field1,
                field2= DBData.field2,
                field3= DBData.field3,
               
            });

List1.AddRange(List2);
```