# Why does LINQ query affect original list?

Tags: c#, list, linq, filtering

I am working on filtering a list using LINQ and came across a strange problem.

The code looks as follows:

```
filteredUsers = users.Where(x => x.ResourceTypeUserVms
        .Any(x => x.ResourceUserVms
        .Any(x => x.MetaData.ToLower().Contains(value))))
        .ToList();

        filteredUsers = filteredUsers
        .Select(x =>
        {
            x.ResourceTypeUserVms = x.ResourceTypeUserVms.Select(y =>
            {
                y.ResourceUserVms = y.ResourceUserVms.Where(s => s.MetaData.ToLower().Contains(value)).ToList();

                return y;
            }).ToList();
            x.ResourceTypeUserVms = x.ResourceTypeUserVms.Where(z => z.ResourceUserVms.Count() > 0).ToList();
            return x;
        }).ToList();
```

The users list contains the original data and the filteredUsers should only contain the filtered data. However, when I clear the filter (that means the original data should be displayed again), the users list seems to be manipulated.

Can anyone explain how I get the users list to stay the same no matter what?

Comment: Because the two lists have the same objects in them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573715/list-is-changed-when-i-update-another-list-with-same-data-type . _Probably_ what you want to do is _not_ overwrite `ResourceTypeUserVms` on an existing `x` - but instead create a completely _new_ object (with the `ResourceTypeUserVms` set however you would like) and return that instead.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you clear the filter please? I expect that is the issue rather than how the filter is created. Also what technology are you using to display your lists? Is it WPF, WinUI, WinForms, ASP.Net Web Forms, ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: @mjwills I can't quite follow, could you maybe provide a code example?

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to stop doing `return x;` (and same for `return y;`) - well technically the issue isn't those returns, but the assignments to their properties just prior. You need to `new` up whatever type `x` is, and populate it as you need it. Then return _that_. As is, you are picking up a bowl of lollies, throwing out half of the lollies, and then confused where the lollies went. So you need to create a _new_ bowl of lollies. With two bowls of lollies, throwing out some from one bowl won't impact the other.

Comment: Right, finally got it to work. Your explanation really helped me, thanks a lot @mjwills !

Comment: Awesome - well done!